# Tracking PR deployment time with Jenkins, Grafana and Prometheus

Tags: jenkins, prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to get time, how long does it take for PR to be deployed into for example stage environment.
Let's assume, when PR is merged to main branch, related job is run. After this job, another one is run, and then another job which will deploy changes to stage environment. First job triggers second job, and second job triggers third job. So to get real time how long does it take for PR to be deployed, I need to have end of third job and start of the first job. I'm passing start time of first job as parameter to second job and so on. In addition, I'm passing also name of PR.

```
build job: 'job2Parameter', wait: false, parameters: [
                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'PR', value: "PR-1234"],
                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'firstStart', value: "${job1Timestamp}"]
            ]
```

As a final result I would like to have Grafana dashbord, which will display time for specific PR. Unfortunately, I can't find Prometheus metric with information about start/stop job time. So after third job (deploy) I run another job (summaryTime) and pass: `first job start time`, `PR`, `end of third job time`. I was thinking it will allow me, to get information about times in Grafana, but I was wrong.While trying to do query I have: `default_jenkins_builds_build_duration_milliseconds{jenkins_job="summaryTime", parameters="PR=PR-1234;thirdStop=1691752401187;firstStart=1691752322966"}`. What I wanted with my approach is to deliver PR name to Grafana and return values like `firstStart` and `firstStop` to just have difference in times. Is there an easy way to fix this or should I completely rethink my approach?

Comment: Depends on how you want to visualize this time: if in table, you could probably use a couple of transformations. If in something like Stat panel - I don't think it achievable with your current approach.

Comment: I think table will be enough, because you have data related only to PR and you won't have multiple, the same PRs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the difference in table:

1. Create panel with query `default_jenkins_builds_build_duration_milliseconds{jenkins_job="summaryTime"}`,
2. Set query result [format](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/query-editor/#format) to Table,
3. Add following Transformations:

   1. **Extract fields**: Source *parameters*, Format *Key+value pairs*
   2. **Convert field type**: Field *firstStart* as *Number*, same for *thirdStop*,
   3. **Add field from calculation**: Mode *Binary operation*, Operation *thirdStop - firstStart*.
4. Panel options > Overrides > <kbd>+ Add field override</kbd> > Field with name > Name of field you used in 3.3 > <kbd>+ Add override property</kbd> > Standard options > Unit > Time > milliseconds (ms)

Comment: Okey, I got some data displayed, but for sure it will be much better if Prometheus sees all parameters as different label, not one long string. In addition, is there a possibility to use grafana variable to manipulate PR I want to get time?

Comment: @Frendom, storing random data in labels is definitely not strong side of Prometheus. But it wasn't designed for this, so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: @Frendom, I'm not sure I got your question about variable. Do want to know how to extract variable from this metric? Or how to use it for filtering?

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to use it for filtering, but I was able to deal with that, thanks!